# HTTP Error 500.30 - ANCM In-Process Start Failure when using azure keyvault

Tags: azure-keyvault, asp.net-core-3.1, github-actions, azure-webapps

I am using GitHub Action for CI/CD to Azure web app in .NET core 3.1 MVC. I am able to get the secrets from Azure key vault in localhost but when I browse the app hosted in azure portal (xyz.azurewebsites.net), I get HTTP Error 500.30 - ANCM In-Process Start Failure.

I have given permission to Key Vault to App from Access Policies with GET and LIST
[image]

My program.cs file is as below
[image]

Comment: Do you use a User Managed identity for you Azure Web App ?

Comment: Read it through https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/troubleshoot-azure-iis?view=aspnetcore-3.1#50030-in-process-startup-failure There is another possible cause (and probably others).

Comment: Possiblly the KeyVaultEndpoint is not correct